# What does a proceeding exclamation mark do for JSDoc @type tag?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, google-closure-compiler, jsdoc

VS Code parses the following as if there were no exclamation mark, without any errors:

```
const el = /** @type {HTMLElement!} */ (document.getElementById("abc"));
```

What does it do? The official JSDoc documentation says [only about preceding marks](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html):

> Indicates that the value is of the specified type, but cannot be null.

Not sure what proceeding marks do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*TLDR*:  `!HTMLElement` and `HTMLElement!` are the same annotation, practically speaking.

---

```
const el = /** @type {HTMLElement!} */ (document.getElementById("abc"));
```

Is a type cast. It says that `document.getElementById("abc")` is an HTMLElement, and not null. The annotation was likely added because [getElementById](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/CR-DOM-Level-2-20000510/core.html#ID-getElBId) returns either an HTMLElement or null.

The author of this line should be 100% confident that an element with an id of `abc` exists, because after this cast is made, the Closure Compiler will treat this type as an `HTMLElement`, instead of possibly an `HTMLElement` or `null`.

Types used in casting follow the same rules as types outside of casting, so to demonstrate using these types directly, the examples that follow do not use casting.

As OP says, in Closure Compiler the exclamation mark means the type must exist, and cannot be `null`. Additionally, a question mark means it could be the type or it could be `null`.

Take for example the following code:

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @output_file_name default.js
// @formatting pretty_print
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

const body = document.querySelector('body');

const /** @export {Element!} */ n1 = body;
const /** @export {!Element} */ n2 = body;
const /** @export {Element} */ n3 = null;
const /** @export {?Element} */ n4 = null;
const /** @export {Element?} */ n5 = null;

console.log({
  n1,
  n2,
  n3,
  n4,
})
```

And [run it through the Closure Compiler](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540output_file_name%2520default.js%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540formatting%2520pretty_print%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250Aconst%2520body%2520%253D%2520document.querySelector(%27body%27)%253B%250A%250Aconst%2520%252F**%2520%2540export%2520%257BElement!%257D%2520*%252F%2520n1%2520%253D%2520body%253B%250Aconst%2520%252F**%2520%2540export%2520%257B!Element%257D%2520*%252F%2520n2%2520%253D%2520body%253B%250Aconst%2520%252F**%2520%2540export%2520%257BElement%257D%2520*%252F%2520n3%2520%253D%2520null%253B%250Aconst%2520%252F**%2520%2540export%2520%257B%253FElement%257D%2520*%252F%2520n4%2520%253D%2520null%253B%250Aconst%2520%252F**%2520%2540export%2520%257BElement%253F%257D%2520*%252F%2520n5%2520%253D%2520null%253B%250A%250Aconsole.log(%257B%250A%2520%2520n1%252C%250A%2520%2520n2%252C%250A%2520%2520n3%252C%250A%2520%2520n4%252C%250A%257D)), here are the warnings the compiler generates:

```
JSC_TYPE_MISMATCH: initializing variable
found   : (Element|null)
required: Element at line 3 character 37
const /** @export {Element!} */ n1 = body;
                                     ^
JSC_TYPE_MISMATCH: initializing variable
found   : (Element|null)
required: Element at line 4 character 37
const /** @export {!Element} */ n2 = body;
                                     ^
```

Note that `body` is returned by `document.querySelector` with a type of `{?Element}` , which we've said the compiler understands can be either an `Element` or `null`, a.k.a. `Element|null`. This example shows that the notation can also be expressed as `?Element` or `Element?`.

Comment: Oh, so `!HTMLElement` and `HTMLElement!` is exactly same!

Comment: Using it after the type notation makes more sense to me, since in regular JS using the exclamation mark in front can mark the opposite. `(!true === false)` equals: `true`. Another point: From a grammar perspective, when you add the question mark after the type definition you question whether or not it's true.

Comment: Agreed Remi, In my experience the `!` or `?` operators virtually always precede the type. Your example though, I think is better restated: `!(true == false)`.